# How do I codesign a JavaFX application through the NetBeans API?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, javafx, code-signing

I found this in the netbeans IDE:
[image]

I was pretty excited because up until this point I've been code signing my JavaFX projects like this:

```
<fx:signjar  keystore = "${comodo.key.store}"
                alias = "${comodo.key.alias}"
            storetype = "PKCS12"
              keypass = "${comodo.key.pass}"
            storepass = "${comodo.key.storepass}"
                  jar = "${JFX.build.dir}/${JFXProject.name}.jar"
              destdir = "${JFX.sign.dir}"/>
```

Which is fine. I mean, it works great and all and there's nothing wrong with it but I would really love to be able to use the Netbeans API code signer interface directly rather than drop the XML into the build file. I filled in the information in the way that seemed correct by taking the values I had in place in the XML and putting them into the interface but it didn't work and I got an error:

```
Going to create default keystore in "/*Not saying but it was the file name*/"
Generating Key for 3d637e48-f0d8-11e3-825a-20cf305e6ed4
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

This shouldn't even need to happen should it? I mean, I've been using this certificate for a while directly in the ant script for a while with no problem, so why is it happening now?
A bit more information: this is a Comodo certificate (if that helps).

What am I doing wrong here?